# Django - update_index updates both test and production sites

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

This is a weird one that I cannot figure out.

I have two databases - test and production.

I have two websites - test and production.

Django is using elasticsearch for the indexing.

They are running off of different servers, have different IP address, etc.

There is no link at all between the two databases. They are maintained independently.

However, when I run `update_index` or `rebuild_index` on either the production or test site, the indexes on BOTH sites are getting updates. The two databases still remain independent and the data there is not transferred at all.

It doesn't matter if I run the command on test or on production - both will be updated from either source.

This is obviously causing me many problems and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

TEST DATABASE AND HAYSTACK CONNECTION -

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        # Ends with "postgresql_psycopg2", "mysql", "sqlite3" or "oracle".
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.oracle",
        # DB name or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        "NAME": "--",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "USER": "--",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "PASSWORD": "--",
        # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        "HOST": <test-database>,
        # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        "PORT": "--",
    }
}

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'products_index'
    }
}
```

PRODUCTION DATABASE AND HAYSTACK CONNECTION

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        # Ends with "postgresql_psycopg2", "mysql", "sqlite3" or "oracle".
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.oracle",
        # DB name or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        "NAME": "--",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "USER": "--",
        # Not used with sqlite3.
        "PASSWORD": "--",
        # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        "HOST": "<production-database>",
        # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        "PORT": "--",
    }
}
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
  'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
  'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
  'INDEX_NAME': 'products_index',
  },
}
```

I've been tearing my hair out and can't seem to find how the two are possibly communicating and updating each other! Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Test and production server pointing to same ES server. Hope that answer your question.